# Specific executable file name creates syntax error in C

Tags: c, makefile, syntax-error, executable

I'm creating a project and I need to call my executable file name "cluster".

I created a makefile and as long as I call my executable file name by any name other then "cluster" and runs it, it works fine.

However, when I'm calling the file name "cluster" -> make all -> executing (with the name "cluster") I receive the following error:

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SubOf.png)

What could be the cause of this error? I must be able to call the executable file name that specific name.

Comment: Please do not post code as images or links to images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question. As for the actual problem, it's possible that there is a different `cluster` command in your path.

Comment: You're not running your program but the `cluster` program from `graphviz`. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on linux, type

```
which cluster
```

You will probably find a program called cluster on your path.  To execute the one you have made, either change the name to something like Cluster or

```
./cluster testGraph8 outputfile
```

The ./ uses the one in the current directory.